# Sending action to item controller from array controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple ArrayController which has the itemController attribute defined. I'd like to send an action from the ArrayController to each item's backing controller. I'm not sure how to "bubble down" this action though.

Comment: I realized that the ArrayController has a _subControllers property in which I can use to invoke the various actions. Would making use of this field become problematic?

Comment: Try not to use private properties, as those can change each time you update a library (Ember.js in this case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the controller itself and that returns the item controller.

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'foo',
  actions:{
    talkToChildren:function(){
      this.forEach(function(itemController){
        itemController.send('foo');
      });
    }
  }
});

App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  count: 1,
  actions:{
    foo:function(){
      this.incrementProperty('count');
    }
  }
})
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fagosifu/1/edit